# How do I write to a hidden file?

Tags: c#, file, hidden

I am using the TextWriter to try to write to a hidden file, and it is throwing an exception. I can't seem to figure out how to write to a hidden file.

```
using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(filename))
{
    tw.WriteLine("foo");
    tw.Close();
}
```

Exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 
Access to the path 'E:\*\media\Photos\2006-08\.picasa.ini' is denied.
```

How can I write to a hidden file?

Comment: What is the exception it is throwing?

Comment: What exception is it throwing?

Comment: Oh, hey, what exception is it throwing?

Comment: I don't know if anybody is looking for it, but I added the exception just in case.

Comment: I like how the answers are as redundant as the comments.

Comment: @eyelidlessness: in this question the answers are in high quantity, not quality... ;)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that kind of a `File.Exists()` check is done internally, which fails if the file is hidden (e.g. tries to do a `FileMode.Create` on a file which already exists).

Therefore, use `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` to make sure that the file is opened or created even if it is hidden, or just `FileMode.Open` if you do not want to create it if it doesn't exist.

When `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` is used though, the file will not be truncated, so you should set its length at the end to make sure that there is no leftover after the end of the text.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open)) {
  using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(fs)) {
    // Write your data here...
    tw.WriteLine("foo");
    // Flush the writer in order to get a correct stream position for truncating
    tw.Flush();
    // Set the stream length to the current position in order to truncate leftover text
    fs.SetLength(fs.Position);
  }
}
```

If you use .NET 4.5 or later, there is a new overload which prevents the disposal of the `StreamWriter` to also dispose the underlying stream. The code could then be written slighly more intuitively like this:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open)) {
  using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8, 1024, true)) {
    // Write your data here...
    tw.WriteLine("foo");
  }
  // Set the stream length to the current position in order to truncate leftover text
  fs.SetLength(fs.Position);
}
```

Comment: Upvoted because this is the correct operation... not "unhide the file, write to it, then hide it again" process

Comment: Thank you for clarifying exactly WHY this happens, as I didn't see how a "hidden" attribute affected file permissions.

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde, you're welcome. Unfortunately most people visiting this question don't seem to realize that changing the attributes back and forth is not really a solution but just a brittle workaround.

Comment: tw.Close() is unnesessary

Comment: @SergeyT You're of course correct, but I included it in the answer because this was the OP's snippet in the question. I just modified the `StreamWriter` creation to show how to deal with the hidden file.

Comment: @Lucero I think that your answer is not consistent with OP's. `FileMode.Create` will truncate the existing file, however `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` not. You should call something like `fs.SetLength(fs.Position)`.

Comment: @TN Good point - if the written content is shorter than the original content this will be necessary. Edited, thanks.

Comment: @Lucero Shouldn't the fourth parameter of the `StreamWriter` in your second example be `true`? The parameter is called `leaveOpen` and we need this so the `FileStream` length can be set, right?

Comment: @toXel Good catch, fixed.

Answer (score 22):

EDIT 2: This answer solve the problem, but is not the correct way to deal with the problem. You should look for Lucero's answer.

---

Took this answer from: http://www.dotnetspark.com/Forum/314-accessing-hidden-files-and-write-it.aspx

1- Set File as Visible so it can be overwritten

```
// Get file info
FileInfo myFile= new FileInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\hiddenFile.txt");

// Remove the hidden attribute of the file
myFile.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.Hidden;
```

2- Make changes to the file

```
// Do foo...
```

3- Set back file as hidden

```
// Put it back as hidden
myFile.Attributes |= FileAttributes.Hidden;
```

EDIT: I fixed some problem on my answer as mentionned by briler

Comment: unsetting the hidden attribute and then resetting hidden after you've written to the file is rife with so many problems.  Just use one of the FileStream overloads that handles this properly, as mentioned in @Lucero answer.

Comment: see the answer of @Lucero there is no need to change attributes to write to a hidden file.

Answer (score 12):

Edit : Pierre-Luc Champigny answer **was** inccorect, but now fixed according to mine,
I'm Leaving it behind as reference

```
myFile.Attributes |= FileAttributes.Normal;
```

doesn't remove the Hidden attribute from the file.
in order to remove unhidden attribute use :

```
FileInfo .Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.Hidden;
```

This code checks if the file exists it make it unhidden. before writing
once finish it set it as hidden again.
I also set the normal attribute in case the didn't exist - you do not have to use it

```
// if do not exists it creates it.
FileInfo FileInfo = new FileInfo(FileName);
if (true == FileInfo .Exists)
{
   // remove the hidden attribute from the file
   FileInfo .Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.Hidden; 
} //if it doesn't exist StreamWriter will create it
using (StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter(FileName))
{
   fileWriter.WriteLine("Write something");
}
 // set the file as hidden
FileInfo.Attributes |= FileAttributes.Hidden;
```

Comment: Well i fixed the problem on my answer, sorry about that

Comment: Why unhide the file in the first place?  Your modifying the state of the file.

Comment: Because you will usually get an UnauthorizedAccessException, see the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

If that's an option for you you could try to use `File.SetAttributes` to remove the hidden attribute temporarily, do your work and then set it back to the previous state.

Comment: bad option, as I mentioned on another answer

Answer (score 0):

You can unhide the file before writing into it and after complete writing hide it again.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've opened a file, you can change its attributes (including to readonly) and continue writing to it. This is one way to prevent a file from being overwritten by other processes.

So it would seem to be possible to unhide the file, open it, then reset it to hidden, even while you've got it open.

For example, the following code works:

```
public void WriteToHiddenFile(string fname)
{
    TextWriter    outf;
    FileInfo      info;  

    info = new FileInfo(fname);
    info.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;    // Set file to unhidden
    outf = new StreamWriter(fname);             // Open file for writing
    info.Attributes = FileAttributes.Hidden;    // Set back to hidden
    outf.WriteLine("test output.");             // Write to file
    outf.Close();                               // Close file
}
```

Note that the file remains hidden while the process writes to it.

Comment: Bad option.  If something happens between unsetting the hidden attribute and resetting the hidden attribute, you've changed the state of the file unnecessarily.  Simple use an overload of FileStream ctor.