# XmlTextWriter - Access to the path is denied

Tags: c#, xml

This seems to be quite simple but I can't seem to figure out the problem

```
public static string destinationFile;

[STAThread]
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //doing something and then calling convert method
}

private static void convert(object source, FileSystemEventArgs f)
{
    if (check(FileName))
    {
        //doing something

        XmlTextWriter myWriter = new XmlTextWriter(destinationFile, null);

        //doing something
    }
}

private static bool check(string filename)
{
    //check the file and return a boolean result
    if (sometest)
    {
        destinationFile = @"d:/GS";
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

When I run this I get:

```
The process failed:
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied
```

May I know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Run your program as `Administrator` and try again

Comment: I'm using windows xp and am already in the administrator account

Comment: Are you sure administrators have access to the folder?

Comment: Check if you have full access-Read/Write to the destination file

Comment: Yes, I had a doubt earlier, then I put everyone on that folder with full access

Comment: @user726720, is the D:\GS an existing folder?

Comment: I did try changing it to c: temporary but I'm getting the same error

Comment: This program was working until I change the 'destinationFile' variable to be a static global, before I was defining within the convert method, now because I want to access/change this in the check method as well - so I decided to go global.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to write to a file, that is actually already a folder on your filesystem.

In your `check` method, you set `destinationFile` to "D:\GS", and later you use `destinationFile` as the target of your `XmlTextWriter`.

Probably you want something as:

```
  XmlTextWriter myWriter = new XmlTextWriter(Path.Combine(destinationFile, FileName), null);
```

Comment: This didn't work exactly but inspired from this view I figured out my problem. I was using the variables wrong. I was using fullpath instead of the name, which was creating a problem. But thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As misleading as the exception message is, this may indicate that the file is hidden.

You can check this via right-click from the Windows Explorer => Properties. Is the the "Hidden" CheckBox activated? If yes, uncheck it and try again.

You can also remove it in the code of your application (if the business logic allows for this). You can find example code for this here: [How do I write to a hidden file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2247011/219344)

Comment: I'm trying to create xml file. The exception is raised with the XMLTEXTwriter

Answer (score 0):

To start debugging this I would probably put some very simple xml located at that same location

```
var xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><hello><world>hello world</world></hello>";
 XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
 xdoc.Save("d:\test.xml");
```

then try to read in the new path
see if your xml reader can access the test file